# using client machine locale for i18n

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, locale

I'm trying to get my application work according to the OS locale of the client machine. For now it works with the locale of server machine. I'm using string frmae work. Apache Tomcat 7 is used as the server. Here is the configuration I used. Any help would be appriciated.

```
     <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="language" />
    </bean>


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


<!--     Register the welcome.properties -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
                    <list>
                        <value>i18n.api/api</value>
                        <value>i18n.exceptions/exceptions</value> 
                        <value>i18n.common/common</value>   
                        <value>i18n.login/login</value>
                        <value>i18n.plan/plan</value>
                        <value>i18n.customer/customer</value>
                        <value>org.springframework.security.messages</value> 
                        <value>org.hibernate.validator.ValidationMessages</value> 
                    </list>
                </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get my application work according to the OS locale of the client machine"? What behaviour should be specific to the (any?) client?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [supported handler method argument types on Spring doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments). You can inject the user's Locale on your handler method like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/home")
public String home(Locale userLocale) {
    // do something with userLocale

    return "home";
}
```

Locale is of type java.util.Locale.

Also have a look at `getLocale()` method of [ServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html). The client has to provide Accept-Language header on their request, otherwise server's locale is used. I'm assuming Spring behave in the same fashion as this